# Unable to scrape news headings from Hacker news

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape only the top news article's headline and link from hacker news.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class HnItem(scrapy.Item):
    title=scrapy.Field()
    link=scrapy.Field()

class HnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="hn"
    allowed_domains=["https://news.ycombinator.com"]
    start_urls=["https://news.ycombinator.com/"]
    def parse(self,response):
        item=HnItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="hnmain"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="hnmain"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a/@href').extract()
        print item['title']
        print item['link']
```

But this returns an empty list.

P.S. I am a beginner in python and in scrapy.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors when you run it or does it just print empty lists?

Comment: allowed_domains is a collection of domains, not URLs. In this case it should be allowed_domains=["news.ycombinator.com"]. Not sure if that's the cause of your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with when I tried creating a spider:

```
import scrapy

class HnItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()

class HnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hackernews'
    allowed_domains = ['news.ycombinator.com'] # see Javier's comment
    start_urls = ['http://news.ycombinator.com/']

    def parse(self,response):
        sel = scrapy.Selector(response)
        item=HnItem()

        # These xPaths can probably be made more generic
        item['title'] = sel.xpath("//tr[@class='athing']/td[3]/a[@href]/text()").extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath("//tr[@class='athing']/td[3]/a/@href").extract()

        # Do whatever you want with the item. Print,return, etc..
        print item['title']
        print item['link']
```

You can run this from the command line with: `scrapy runspider path/to/your_spider.py`

Comment: In addition, I wanted to add some resources that I highly reccommend: [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/) , [A good sample project](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot), and [W3 Schools xPath intro](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)